# Taxonomy Access modification

Tags: 7, distributions, taxonomy-terms

I would like to edit the standard setup when installing the `Taxonomy Access`-module.
I would like it to be enabled by default and also I want to configure some rules for specific roles. But I need to do this while installing my D7 website. Which is the best way how to do this?

Comment: Are you talking about something like a custom install profile?

Comment: One solution that works is to create a custom module that implements hook_install and executes sql data import.